# Divide by bins with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like below. Index is date time object, ordered by day, divided in 5 minute bins. I have a column called 'col1'. So if I do

```
df['col1']
```

I get:

```
DateTime
2008-04-28 09:40:00     300.0
2008-04-28 09:45:00    -800.0
2008-04-28 09:50:00       0.0
2008-04-28 09:55:00    -100.0
2008-04-28 10:00:00       0.0    
2008-04-29 09:40:00     500.0
2008-04-29 09:45:00     800.0
2008-04-29 09:50:00     100.0
2008-04-29 09:55:00    -100.0
2008-04-29 10:00:00       0.0
```

I have another dataframe in pandas obtained using groupby in the original dataframe using

```
df2 = df([df.index.time])[['col2']].mean()
```

that outputs:

```
           col2
09:40:00   4603.585657
09:45:00   5547.011952
09:50:00   8532.007952
09:55:00   6175.298805
10:00:00   4236.055777
```

What I would like to do is to divide col1 by col2 for each of the 5 minute bins without using a for loop. To explain better, for all the days, for each bin divide col1 by col2. For example, divide all the 9:40:00 values in col1 by 9:40:00 value in col2.

I have no idea how to begin doing this without a for loop, but I have the impression that it should be doable with pandas.

The expected output is:

```
DateTime
2008-04-28 09:40:00     300.0/4603.585657
2008-04-28 09:45:00    -800.0/5547.011952
2008-04-28 09:50:00       0.0/8532.007952
2008-04-28 09:55:00    -100.0/6175.298805
2008-04-28 10:00:00       0.0/4236.055777  
2008-04-29 09:40:00     500.0/4603.585657
2008-04-29 09:45:00     800.0/5547.011952
2008-04-29 09:50:00     100.0/8532.007952
2008-04-29 09:55:00    -100.0/6175.298805
2008-04-29 10:00:00       0.0/4236.055777
```

Comment: `groupby 5 minutes`? I guess not all cases are like so, but here there are no time steps < than 5min

Comment: sorry, groupby day

Comment: Is what I answered what you're trying to do¿

Comment: I don't know, I am very lost right now. Sorry. I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @python_enthusiast - Can you add expected output?

Comment: So you want to group df1 on a daily basis, and divide each value by its corresponding mean?

Comment: @yatu yes! each 5 minute value divided by the mean on all days for that bin.

Comment: Yeah  based on your update, you want to groupby using only the time of the datetime  index, so use @jezraels sol

Comment: @yatu - Sorry, yatu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need divide by times:

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].div(df.groupby(df.index.time)['col1'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
                      col1   new
DateTime                        
2008-04-28 09:40:00  300.0  0.75
2008-04-28 09:45:00 -800.0  -inf
2008-04-28 09:50:00    0.0  0.00
2008-04-28 09:55:00 -100.0  1.00
2008-04-28 10:00:00    0.0   NaN
2008-04-29 09:40:00  500.0  1.25
2008-04-29 09:45:00  800.0   inf
2008-04-29 09:50:00  100.0  2.00
2008-04-29 09:55:00 -100.0  1.00
2008-04-29 10:00:00    0.0   NaN
```

Or if need divide by days:

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].div(df.groupby(df.index.date)['col1'].transform('mean'))
print (df)
                      col1       new
DateTime                            
2008-04-28 09:40:00  300.0 -2.500000
2008-04-28 09:45:00 -800.0  6.666667
2008-04-28 09:50:00    0.0 -0.000000
2008-04-28 09:55:00 -100.0  0.833333
2008-04-28 10:00:00    0.0 -0.000000
2008-04-29 09:40:00  500.0  1.923077
2008-04-29 09:45:00  800.0  3.076923
2008-04-29 09:50:00  100.0  0.384615
2008-04-29 09:55:00 -100.0 -0.384615
2008-04-29 10:00:00    0.0  0.000000
```

Comment: How does that divide col1 by col2?

Comment: What is `print (df2.index[:10])` ?

Comment: Index([09:35:00, 09:40:00, 09:45:00, 09:50:00, 09:55:00, 10:00:00, 10:05:00,
       10:10:00, 10:15:00, 10:20:00],
      dtype='object')

Comment: @python_enthusiast - and `print (type(df2.index[0]))` ?

Comment: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: sorry, can I ask more questions?

Comment: I don't know how col2 comes in here

Comment: should I change the second col1 by col2?

Comment: @python_enthusiast - Yes, it is up to you. instaed `col2` is used `df.groupby(df.index.time)['col1'].transform('mean')`

Comment: I see! Thanks again!